# Drag UIView and drop to another UIView using UIPanGuesture

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to drag top red circle `UIView` and drop on bottom black circle `UIView`.
I want to drop this red circle when it is on atleast 50% on black circle.
but this method execute only when it perfect location of black circle.
Please give me some solution to do this when it is in black area circle.
Below is my code

```
  if sourceCircleView.frame.contains(destinationCircleView.frame) {
        destinationCircleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        sourceCircleView.isHidden = true
    }
    if sourceCircleView.frame.contains(destinationSquareView.frame) {
        sourceCircleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
            self.sourceCircleView.center = self.sourceCircleViewCenter
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
if sourceCircleView.frame.intersects(destinationCircleView.frame) {

  //
}
```

//
 OR

```
let rect = sourceCircleView.frame.intersection(destinationCircleView.frame)

// here compare width of rect with destinationCircleView.frame for 50% check

 if rect.width >= ( destinationCircleView.frame.width / 2 )  && rect.height >= ( destinationCircleView.frame.height / 2 ) {
   // intersection more than 50%
 }
```